# How to solve "compare to undefined" problem?

Tags: mongodb

I have collections users and orders and i do:

```
user=db.users.find({username:"tom"})
db.orders.find({user_id:user['_id']})
```

And i get this error:

```
Error: error: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "cannot compare to undefined",
        "code" : 2,
        "codeName" : "BadValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns a cursor, maybe try

```
user=db.users.findOne({username:"tom"}); 
if (user != null) 
   db.orders.find({user_id:user['_id']})
```